# LineLegend can't draw rounded dashes?

Tags: plotting, legending, plot-themes, styling

I have a plot with rounded dashes, but LineLegend seems to be unable to draw them.

```
style = {Directive[Black], 
       Directive[Red, Opacity[.5], 
        Dashing[{.02, .015}, 0, CapForm["Round"]]], 
       Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5], 
        Dashing[{.005, .01}, 0, CapForm["Round"]]]};
```

Looks good in a plot:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], E^(-x)}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> style]
```

But not in a line legend:

```
LineLegend[style, {"1", "2", "3"}]
```

For me (V13.2.1.0) the line legend has no dashes at all, rounded or not. If I remove the rounding from `style`, the dashes at least appear with sharp edges, but I want the rounded ones in the plot and I want the legend to match the plot. Is this a bug, and if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphics object in the legend is too small for the dashings to be visible.  You can see this using a larger `LegendMarkerSize`:

```
LineLegend[style, {"1", "2", "3"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {300, 20}]
```

[image]

**Two work-arounds:**

**1.** To get visible dashing in the legend modify `style` to increase the
first argument in `Dashing`:

```
LineLegend[style /. Dashing[a_, b___] :> Dashing[10 a, b], {"1", "2", "3"}]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, specify dashing in absolute lengths (independent of
image size of the parent graphics)  using
[`AbsoluteDashing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteDashing.html)
instead of `Dashing`:

```
style2 = {Directive[Black], 
   Directive[Red, Opacity[.5], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{10, 5}, 0, CapForm["Round"]]], 
   Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{5, 3}, 0, CapForm["Round"]]]};

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], E^(-x)}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> style2]
```

[image]

```
LineLegend[style2, {"1", "2", "3"}]
```

[image]